# Appscript hangs on OSX 10.5.8 using Apache2 Django

Tags: django, apache2, osx-leopard, sourceforge-appscript

I've incorporated appscript into a python 2.6/django installation, and it works fine when served with the django development server, but when using Apache2 I get this:

> The process has forked and you cannot use this CoreFoundation functionality safely. You MUST exec().
>   Break on 
>   __THE_PROCESS_HAS_FORKED_AND_YOU_CANNOT_USE_THIS_COREFOUNDATION_FUNCTIONALITY___YOU_MUST_EXEC__() to debug.

A suggestion was:

> This sounds similar to http://mail.python.org/pipermail/pythonmac-sig/2010-October/022705.html

OSX 10.6 is  a lot stricter than earlier versions about loading OSX API modules before a process is forked. Postponing the imports until after forking is the solution.

The 0.6 C11 version of setuptools triggers this exception by loading Carbon on its own. I believe this might have been fixed.

A way to find who loads what is to look at `sys.modules.keys()` at various stages in the program.

Is this a known issue using appscript and apache2 and if so is there a fix?

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problem. Moving the import from the top of the file to just before the statement that required it fixed a similar problem for me, with the same error message.